# JMSTranslationBundle The annotation "@optional" in property was never imported. Did you maybe forget to add a "use" statement for this annotation?

Tags: php, symfony, annotations

I try extract translations but have many errors

```
php bin/console translation:extract pt --dir=./src/ --output-dir=./app/Resources/translations

[Semantical Error] The annotation "@created" in class InvoiceBundle\Service\CodeGeneratorService was never imported. Did you maybe forget to add a "use" statement for this annotation?

 [Semantical Error] The annotation "@optional" in property Ups\Entity\Tradeability\TariffInfo::$detailId was never imported. Did you maybe forget to add a "use" statement for this annotation?
```

is possible to ignore unknown annotations ?

```
 "jms/translation-bundle": "^1.3",
    "nikic/php-parser": "v1.4.1",
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use https://packagist.org/packages/autumndev/jms-serializer-carbon

just install it and use when creating builder

```
        SerializerBuilder::create()
        ->configureHandlers(
            function(HandlerRegistry $registry) {
                $registry->registerSubscribingHandler(new \AutumnDev\JMS\CarbonHandler());
            }
        )
        ->build()
        ->deserialize($object)
        ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try using [Doctrine IgnoreAnnotation](https://www.doctrine-project.org/api/annotations/latest/Doctrine/Common/Annotations/Annotation/IgnoreAnnotation.html) and see if that fits your purpose.

```
use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\Annotation\IgnoreAnnotation;

/**
  * @IgnoreAnnotation("created")
  * @IgnoreAnnotation("optional")
  */
```